# How to display multiple separate PDF/Excel documents on a website?

Tags: php, html, pdf, iframe, web

I have a client that needs 100s of pricesheets displayed on a website that I am designing for him, one per user. I know how to work with PHP, but I have not found a good way to display the documents on the website specific to each user.

My first solution was to build a function that would search an array for a certain dealer id. That dealer id would be linked to the embed code that would then be inserted into the page via PHP.

The issue with the above method is that it doesn't work with over 3 entries in it. At least from my experience.

Here is my code for the old method. As far as I know, the syntax is correct.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
include_once("check_login_status.php");
$log_dealer = $_SESSION['dealer'];
function assignPriceSheet($log_username) {
    $array = array("<iframe src='pricesheets/Price Sheet.pdf' height='750' width='800'>" => '333333'
                    , "<iframe src='pricesheets/Price Sheet.pdf' height='750' width='800'>" => '115'
                    , "<iframe src='pricesheets/Price Sheet.pdf' height='750' width='800'>" => '122'
                    , "<iframe src='pricesheets/Price Sheet.pdf' height='750' width='800'>" => '136'
                    , "<iframe src='pricesheets/Price Sheet.pdf' height='750' width='800'>" => '137'
                    , "<iframe src='pricesheets/Price Sheet.pdf' height='750' width='800'>" => '167'
                    , "<iframe src='pricesheets/Price Sheet.pdf' height='750' width='800'>" => '169'
                    , "<iframe src='pricesheets/Price Sheet.pdf' height='750' width='800'>" => '172'
                    , "<iframe src='pricesheets/Price Sheet.pdf' height='750' width='800'>" => '173'
                    , "<iframe src='pricesheets/Price Sheet.pdf' height='750' width='800'>" => '199'
                    , "<iframe src='pricesheets/Price Sheet.pdf' height='750' width='800'>" => '208'
                    , "<iframe src='pricesheets/Price Sheet.pdf' height='750' width='800'>" => '217'
                    , "<iframe src='pricesheets/Price Sheet.pdf' height='750' width='800'>" => '596017');
    //Returns the price sheet of the logged in user 
    return array_search($log_username, $array);     
}
```

Normally there would be about 400 more entries in the function (I just wanted to cut down on code length).

An alternative solution would be appreciated!

Comment: Since I don't believe he wants all the four hundred at once, I would load them using Ajax one by one, as needed.

Comment: No he doesn't want all four hundred at once. Each price sheet is assigned to an individual user. I want the user to be able to log in and view their price sheet.  I already have ajax implemented into the website, but how would you display each pricesheet per user?

Comment: Ok, stay tuned and I'll try to explain my approach ;)

Comment: Can you convert the spreadsheets to HTML tables? Much nicer and quicker way to render the data, IMO.

Comment: @halfer Yeah.. There are a couple of apps.. But it's a messy process. Especially with more graphical spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First solution (using array as above)

```
// PHP
// define somewhere this array
$price_list = array (
    "username_1" => "/some-folder/price_list_1.php", 
    "username_2" => "/some-folder/price_list_2.php",
    "username_3" => "/some-folder/price_list_3.php"
);

// your price_list.php file
// you may have all of this in one .php file as well

if(isset($_SESSION) && user_is_authorized()){  // check if the user is logged in
  echo "<iframe src='" . $price_list[$_SESSION['username']] . "' height='750' width='800'>";
}
```

Second solution (without array)

```
// you may name the price_list for each user according to their username and you'll have something like this 
if(isset($_SESSION) && user_is_authorized()){  // check if the user is logged in
  echo "<iframe src='/some-folder/" . $_SESSION['username'] . "_price_list.pdf' height='750' width='800'>";
}
```

On the client side you may have something like this

```
// you may load the price_list on onload or an onclick event
// don't pass any id with URL due to security issues
window.onload = function(){
  var button = document.geElementById('price_list');      
  button.onclick = function(){      
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "pricelist.php";
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById('price_list_container').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  };
};
```

Comment: Man, I don't care if this works or not. I'm going to set your response as the answer to my question.  You freaking rock!!

Comment: I actually have to check out of work for the day, but I will implement one of these solutions tomorrow. Thanks so much!!

Comment: @nate_dawg It must work ;) If you need any further assistance, just drop me a note.